# Looking for an optimized Regex/other solution for mass string matching

Tags: python, regex, python-3.x

A part of my current code involves (pseudo)randomly generating quite a few pairs of strings of various lengths - specifically,

```
shiftspace = {
    2: 20,
    3: 79,
    4: 250,
    5: 791,
    6: 2500,
    7: 7906,
    8: 25000,
    9: 79059
}
```

where key = length of string and value = pairs to be generated. These strings can consist of any variation of the characters 0-9 as well as the character *, which represents any character. The problem comes with the fact that I do not want the sets to contain any repeats. Before I implemented the * I simply checked if a new generated number happened to have been already generated, but now strings can "overlap" despite being nonidentical. For example, the existence of "*056*3" invalidates the generated sequence "*05693" or "905623" or "4056*3"

Currently the solution has been my old ""friend"" Regex. I simply generate a regex string consisting of [char1*][char2*][char3*] etc, which is able to perfectly pick out these matches. The problem is speed - I check the regex against each entry, which balloons in time when higher numbers are reached (the largest possible set to check can reach almost 80k entries). What used to take 5 minutes pre * now takes an hour or more. The code that does all this is below.

```
def regexfit(strang,set):
    regex = ""
    for char in strang:
        regex = regex + "["+char+"*]"
    match = re.search(regex,set)
    if match:
        return True

def shiftgen():
    baseset = [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, "*"]
    shiftset = {}
    keys = list(shiftspace.keys())
    togo = sum(shiftspace.values())
    print(togo)
    for i in range(min(keys), max(keys) + 1):
        print(i)
        shiftset[i] = {}
        shiftset[i]["0"] = 0
        for j in range(shiftspace[i]):
            num = 0
            num2 = 0
            while num == num2:
                num = np.random.choice(baseset, size=i)
                num = "".join(num)
                numset = [i for i in str(num)]
                while any((regexfit(num,x) for x in shiftset[i].keys())):
                    num = np.random.choice(baseset, size=i)
                    num = "".join(num)
                    numset = [i for i in str(num)]
                if len(str(num)) < i:
                    for k in range(i - len(str(num))):
                        numset.append(0)
                num2 = np.random.choice(numset, size=i, replace=False)
                num2 = "".join(num2)
            shiftset[i][num] = num2
            togo = togo - 1
            if togo % 1000 == 0:
                print([num, num2])
        shiftset[i].pop("0")
    return shiftset
```

Things I have considered:

- Concatenating all the sequences to check into one huge string (with a separator char to prevent the regex matching across two sequences) and using the regex on that. I don't know enough about the internals of the *re* engine to know how well that would end up. I'm going to test how fast it runs once my first timed test of the code above is complete.
- Adding these asterisked strings to the database as simply every possible permutation they could take (ie: 2* is added as 21,22,23,etc)>. Then you simply search the database (or, if you generate an asterisked string, you search every permutation and check if any are positive). I highly doubt this will be more efficient but you do never know.
- Some sort of solution where you can generate sequences knowing for sure they have not been previously generated or would be "covered" by a previously generated sequence, eliminating the need to search entirely. Not really a solution because I have no idea how to do this, but just throwing this out there.
- Some sort of more advanced regex expression that evaluates faster.
- Some sort of magic module/formula that is for some reason really good at doing this exact thing.
- Black magic, sacrifices to the Elder Gods, etc.

TL:DR I am looking for a faster way to match sequences with many potential permutations to ensure a permutation was not previously selected.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A few comments, in total too long for a comment...

The regex that you're building in your current code is not actually correct. The character class `[**]` you create when you encounter a `*` in `strang` will only match a `*` in `set`, where you actually want to match *any* character. When you encounter a `*` in `strang` you should actually put a `.` in the regex. For example:

```
regex = ''.join('.' if c == '*' else '[*' + c + ']' for c in strang)
```

Secondly, you should use `re.match` rather than `re.search` as it anchors the search to the start of the string so prevents searching starting at each position in the input. This will give a slight speed improvement.

Finally, it should be faster than using regex (my tests indicate 3-4x) to simply iterate over the characters in each value, comparing them one by one and immediately failing when there is no match e.g.

```
def regexfit(strang,set):
    for a, b in zip(strang, set):
        if a != '*' and b != '*' and a != b:
            return False
    return True
```

Comment: Thanks for the comprehensive answer. I hadn't thought about that interaction with the regex. I'll switch out my function with your *zip* function and see how much faster it ends up being.

Comment: @Arelus no worries. You should leave the question open for now (unaccept the answer) though as other users might have better suggestions...

Comment: I have done so, thanks. I've tested it and it's not quite 3-4x faster, maybe 2x or so (might just be my crappy laptop) but it is a good improvement and also actually works as you pointed out.

Comment: @Arelus no worries - sorry you didn't see the same improvement... you might want to consider also posting this question on https://codereview.stackexchange.com